# Google Webmaster Tools: Adding pages to Webmaster Tools by the bulk

Tags: google-search-console

Is there a method of adding websites in bulk to Google Webmaster Tools?

My host username and password were hacked and all of my sites were injected with malicious scripts. I've cleaned everything up but the sites were d-listed and no longer show up in google search. I need to request reviews for ~150 sites but first I need to add them all to the webmaster tools.

Any non-tedious way of doing this?